# Mysql Query to fetch second lowest marks for all students in a table

Tags: mysql

I have a table like below. I want to fetch the second lowest marks subject only (based on ascending order of the marks) of all students. Please help me the query.

```
id  | student_id | subject_id | marks
--------------------------------------
1   |     1      |      1     |   15
2   |     2      |      1     |   12      
3   |     2      |      3     |   19
4   |     2      |      5     |   14
5   |     4      |      1     |   12
6   |     4      |      2     |   14
7   |     4      |      4     |   13
8   |     4      |      5     |   17
9   |     5      |      1     |   18
10  |     5      |      6     |   19
11  |     5      |      7     |   15
```

So I want result like below. The query should fetch only the second lowest marks subjects for all students in the above table. Here student id 1 has only one subject. so I don't require that one.

```
id  | student_id | subject_id | marks
--------------------------------------
4   |     2      |      5     |   14
7   |     4      |      4     |   13
9   |     5      |      7     |   18
```

Comment: That looks like fun. Do you have a question? Any evidence that you've tried to solve the problem yourself, etc?

Comment: And student 5's second lowest score (which is also their second highest score) is 18 (so id 9)

Comment: Thanks for your comments Strawberry. I have update my question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this with the `substring_index()`/`group_concat()` trick:

```
select substring_index(substring_index(group_concat(id order by marks asc), ',', 2), ',', -1) as id,
       student_id,
       substring_index(substring_index(group_concat(subject_id order by marks asc), ',', 2), ',', -1) as subject_id,
       substring_index(substring_index(group_concat(marks order by marks asc), ',', 2), ',', -1) as marks  
from marks
group by student_id
having count(*) >= 2;
```

Note that this returns the columns as strings instead of the original data type.

Comment: Note that this solution implicitly casts the values returned as strings - not a big deal, but something to consider if ordering the result.

Comment: @Strawberry, as of now we are ok with the query, we don't require ordering the ids.

Answer (score 0):

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS my_table;

CREATE TABLE my_table
(id  INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY
,student_id INT NOT NULL
,subject_id INT NOT NULL
,marks INT NOT NULL
);

INSERT INTO my_table VALUES
(1   ,     1      ,      1     ,   15),
(2   ,     2      ,      1     ,   12),
(3   ,     2      ,      3     ,   19),
(4   ,     2      ,      5     ,   14),
(5   ,     4      ,      1     ,   12),
(6   ,     4      ,      2     ,   14),
(7   ,     4      ,      4     ,   13),
(8   ,     4      ,      5     ,   17),
(9   ,     5      ,      1     ,   18),
(10  ,     5      ,      6     ,   19),
(11  ,     5      ,      7     ,   15);

SELECT x.*
  FROM my_table x 
  JOIN my_table y 
    ON y.student_id = x.student_id 
   AND y.marks <= x.marks 
 GROUP  
    BY x.id 
HAVING COUNT(y.id) = 2;

+----+------------+------------+-------+
| id | student_id | subject_id | marks |
+----+------------+------------+-------+
|  4 |          2 |          5 |    14 |
|  7 |          4 |          4 |    13 |
|  9 |          5 |          1 |    18 |
+----+------------+------------+-------+
```